# Using the pretty time library to show a time in a human readable format in JSF

Tags: jsf, datetime, time, jsf-2.2, prettytime

I happened to use [pretty time](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) 1.0.6 to display an interval between two points in time in a human readable format.

There is an in-built JSF converter,

```
com.ocpsoft.pretty.time.web.jsf.PrettyTimeConverter
```

but it supports only `java.util.Date` objects.

I happened to use the following converter for `org.joda.time.DateTime`

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public final class PrettyJodaTimeConverter extends PrettyTimeConverter
{
    @Override
    public String getAsString(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent component, final Object value)
    {
        if (value instanceof DateTime) {
            return super.getAsString(context, component, ((DateTime) value).toDate());
        } else {
            return super.getAsString(context, component, value);
        }
    }
}
```

This displays an interval, for example, "4 hours ago" on `<h:outputText>`, for example

```
<h:outputText value="#{productInquiryManagedBean.lastInquiry}"
              converter="#{prettyJodaTimeConverter}"/>
```

But I need to display a message on `<p:growl>` (or `<p:messages>`, `<h:messages>`) based on a conditional check in a JSF managed bean. Therefore, this converter cannot be used (please suggest, if it can be used). Instead, I need to manually format it in the managed bean in question like so,

```
private DateTime lastInquiry;
private String emailId;
private Product product;

if(productInquiryService.isPeriodExpired(30, emailId, product))
{
    lastInquiry=productInquiryService.getDateTimeOfLastInquiry(email, product);

    Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
    PrettyTime time=new PrettyTime(lastInquiry.toDate(), locale);
    time.setLocale(locale);

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, Utility.getMessage("faces.message.error"), Utility.getMessage("inquiry.min.time.expire", time.format(new Date()))));
}
```

This displays a message on `<p:growl>` like - "You made an inquiry **4 hours from now**".

Can this message format be changed to "You made an inquiry **4 hours ago**" exactly as displayed on `<h:outputText>` as shown above?

Also, the interval format displayed here is not localized to a particular locate from a resource bundle. It always seems to be using its default locale. The message produced by `PrettyTime#format()` should be localized.

---

I was passing wrong parameters to the constructor. Hence the wrong message indicating a future time. They should be like as follows.

```
PrettyTime time=new PrettyTime(new Date(), locale);
time.format(lastInquiry.toDate());
//lastInquiry is fetched from the database which a customer made an inquiry on.
```

It now displays the correct (past time) format like "4 hours ago".

Regarding the locale I was looking for was `HI` (actually `hi_IN`, Hindi in India) is not available in the resource bundles (in the `com.ocpsoft.pretty.time.i18n` package) supplied in the library even though it is mentioned there in the *[i18n and multiple-languages support](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/)* section.

Comment: One work around, you can do it in javascript, make an inputHidden with the converter, register onchange, when it's changed feed the growl with the value and show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was passing wrong parameters to the constructor. Hence the wrong message indicating a future time. They should be like as follows.

```
PrettyTime time=new PrettyTime(new Date(), locale);
time.format(lastInquiry.toDate());
//lastInquiry is fetched from the database which a customer made an inquiry on.
```

The locale `HI` (for Hindi) and many others are available in the latest version [3.2.5 final](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ocpsoft/prettytime/prettytime/).

---

The JSF converter,

```
com.ocpsoft.pretty.time.web.jsf.PrettyTimeConverter
```

has been repackaged to

```
org.ocpsoft.prettytime.jsf.PrettyTimeConverter
```

and has been moved to a separate jar file [prettytime-integration-jsf](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ocpsoft/prettytime/prettytime-integration-jsf/).

In addition to the core jar file, this jar file is also needed, if you want to use this converter in JSF.